# d3 js topojson colors don't show

Tags: d3.js, choropleth

My question is about making a choropleth of US counties using d3 js. I've merged a dataset (providing a value for each US county) with topojson data for the US. When I console.log the topojson data, the required value appears and I can pick out a value for any given index.
I've also provided a range of colors in a scaleQuantile scale and set the domain to be the extent of values. Again, I can console.log colorScale(value) and get back a color, and invertExtent the color to see the range of colors, so that appears to be working.
My problem is with setting the fill attribute. The data value I want is stored in data.objects.counties.geometries, but when I set that in the topojson.feature function, the map doesn't show at all. So I tried instead adding the geometries to the fill function itself, but get a map of all-black US counties, even when I set the default color to blue. Here is the relevant code, this is my first choropleth attempt (and first stackoverflow question) and I'd be grateful for any help. Thank you

```
 svg.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties).features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", function (d){
   var value = geometries.d.value;
   if (value) {
     return colorScale(value);
   } else {
     return "blue";
   }
 });
```

Comment: use a `console.log` to see what `d` is and then decide how to get the `value` you want, most likely `value` is `undefined`

Comment: Can you add enough data and code to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example? I would imagine that the problem is with `geometries.d.value` -- either `geometries` has not been initialised / defined, or you want `geometries[d.value]` rather than `geometries.d.value`.